# Azure Devops Server needing to see all releases done in 24 hours from collection without iterating through each team project

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We use Azure Devops Server 2021.  There is an api to list releases, but this is only at the project level.  I am looking for an API or something at the Collection level where I could get the information.  All releases do go though a single agent pool.

Comment: Retrieve the projects in the collection. Iterate over the projects. List releases for each project.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Daniel Mann](https://stackoverflow.com/users/781754/daniel-mann) Posting your suggestion as an answer to help community members.

"Retrieve the projects in the collection. Iterate over the projects. List releases for each project."

For more information please refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/manage-project-collections?view=azure-devops-2020#create-a-project-collection) .